# Applying Map Algebra to List of Rasters and Saving New File in New Directory?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, error-000732

I am trying to multiply each raster by coefficient using Map Algebra in Python. I receive the following error for the code below:

> calcRaster.save(calcRasterName) AttributeError: 'unicode' object has
>   no attribute 'save'

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

env.workspace = r"C:\SomeFolder"
outFolder = r"C:\SomeFolder"

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()
for inRaster in rasters:
    calcRaster = inRaster * 720
    calcRasterName = outFolder + "/" + calcRaster
    calcRaster.save(calcRasterName)
```

Based on some searching,  I redefined the calcRaster variable to:

```
  calcRaster = (Raster(inRaster) * 720)
```

However, I receive some comments and a new error:

> File "C:\Users\rrotz\Desktop\Pycharm\RasterCalculator.py", line 13, in
>   
>       calcRasterName = outFolder + "/" + calcRaster
>
> File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 4329, in
>   Plus
>       in_raster_or_constant2)
>
> File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
>       result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\ArcPy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 4326, in
>   Wrapper
>       ["Plus", in_raster_or_constant1, in_raster_or_constant2])
>
> RuntimeError: ERROR 000732: Input Raster: Dataset S:\Group
>   Projects\HDF5\2 Tiff Data\8 Monthly Scaled/ does not exist or is not
>   supported

The last RunTimeError is regarding the outfolder path that I designated for the final calculated rasters.

Answer (score 2):

`calcRaster` is a temporary raster, not a text string. You will need to find another way of naming your result, like `outRasterName = '{}720'.format(inRaster)`.

Python has tools for creating complete path names from path fragments (folder & file names) use `os.path.join` like this: `CalcRasterName = os.path.join(outFolder, outRasterName)`.

Comment: Thanks Bjorn, I edited the code am still getting an error:
    
    outRasterName = '{}720'.format(inRaster)
    calcRasterName = os.path.join(outFolder, outRasterName)
    outRasterName.save(calcRasterName)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'save' 

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You still want to save calcRaster which has the value (arcpy.Raster(InRaster) * 720), so it should be calcRaster.save(CalcRasterName). Beware the file extension! if your input raster is myRaster.tif your CalcRasterName = myRaster.tif720 which isn't a recognized extension. Use FileName, FileExt = os.path.splitext(inRaster) then CalcRasterName ='{}_720{}'.format(FileName,FileExt) to make the new name MyRaster_720.tif in this example.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the code working using the following approach.

```
import arcpy,os,sys,string
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

input_folder = r'SomeFolder'
arcpy.env.workspace = input_folder
output_folder = r'SomeFolder'

#Set reflectance constant
const = 672

# Get raster list, loop through and multiply be constant
raster_list = arcpy.ListRasters()
for inRaster in raster_list:
      print inRaster
      rast_mult = Raster(inRaster) * const 
      raster_mult_out = output_folder + os.sep + inRaster + ".tif"
      rast_mult.save(raster_mult_out)
```

I'll post another version as advised above shortly. Thanks all!